# Presenting ViewController using UserNotifications didReceive responce

Tags: ios, swift

I've a LocalNotification class with UserNotifications implemented in it. I've created segue between my initial ViewController and CheckViewController i need to present. That's my `didReceive responce` func

`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nav = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
        let mainViewController = nav.topViewController as! ViewController
        mainViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CheckSegue", sender: nil)
    }`

But still all i get - is initial ViewController. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `MainViewController` the inital view controller? If so, the instance that you see is the application's root. You are creating an entirely new instance that is not visible.

Try

```
let nav = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
```

instead of

```
let nav = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
```

Comment: but i'm getting an error if i'm not on initial view

Comment: Yeah, you would probably need to navigate back to the initial view first for this to work -- maybe pop the navigation controller to its root so that you're back at the initial view and then perform the segue?